# Subject Pools Affecting Data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

Please correct me if this is not the right question, I'm not sure how to phrase this. I am trying to see the affect that a pool of subjects will have on statistics. Let's say I have 100 people participating in a study. At the end of the study, I have a p-value of <.05. I want to see how that value would change if I now say that 10% of the subjects who participated in the study should not have. That 10% of subjects provided bad data, and should not have been in the study, so I want to know how/if the p-value will change with the exclusion of those patients.

Comment: Could you explain how the obvious solution of removing those patients and recomputing the p-value wouldn't work?  That would help us understand your question.

Comment: @whuber thank you for your question. It is because I am not testing the study itself but rather the screening process. I also do not provide the data itself, so I cannot remove the patients. I want to show that the screening process protected 10% of the data and what would happen if the 10% wasn't screened. Does that provide some more context?

Comment: You seem to describe a *breakdown point,* which is a fundamental concept of *robust statistics.*  Different procedures have different breakdown points, so the answer will depend on the study and how the p-value is computed.

Comment: @whuber thank you, would you be able to lead me to some literature/videos that will help me use this concept?

Comment: The literature is huge, so you would be best off searching materials you think would be most accessible to you, using the italicized keywords I offered.